# select2 image and text

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm trying to make a select of icons, with icon image and text. I managed to display image and text but now I have a problem by selecting it. I want to select only `item.ikona` but I guess it selects the whole `text:` value and gives me `object Object`. I could solve this by changing `text:` only into `item.ikona`, but then the picture won't be displayed.

My HTML

```
<select class="ikonos" id="ikona" name="ikona"></select>
```

My Script

```
$('.ikonos').select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 2,
    closeOnSelect: true,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: 'Įveskite anglišką ikonos pavadinimą',
   "language": {
       "noResults": function(){
           return "Rezultatų nėra";
       }
   },

    ajax: {
        url: '/palanga/create/fetch',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",

    processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    id: item.ikona,
                    text: $('<img src="/ikona/'+item.ikona+'">'+'<span class="icon_txt">'+item.ikona.replace('.png','')+'</span>')
                } 
            })
        }; 
    }
    }
});
```

Fetch

```
public function fetch(Request $request)
{
    $data = [];
    if($request->has('q')){
        $search = $request->q;
        $data =Ikona::select("ikona")
                ->where('ikona','LIKE',"%$search%")
                ->take(5)->get();
    }
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Comment: Hi , can you make your code runnable ?

Comment: Hey, its pretty hard, cause these values come form database and I use Laravel..

Comment: I added fetch from controller code..

Comment: Check [this](https://select2.org/selections) out might help .